# Android emulator is unable to open some apps

Tags: android, emulation

Hi friends I'm new to programming and start making my new project in python automation but I'm currently
facing an issue as some apps are not working on emulator and I tried every wear but don't found any result
mainly following error is showing on the app:-
#Launching the app on emulator is blocked.
Please if any one know how to solve this problem tell me so I can complete my project.
Thanks and If any other detail that I forgot to tell or specifies in this post please tell me as it is my first post.

Comment: which app are you trying to launch?

Comment: please provide more information & what you did to compel this

Comment: Thanks for replying the thing I want to do is to bypass emulator detection on certain kind of apps . So if you know how to do that it will be really helpful. Thanks.